# How to fix 'str' object is not callable in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hi Everyone I made A Blog but when i delete post i get this error i'm using django latest version:

```
TypeError at /post/(?P3\d+)/remove/
'str' object is not callable'
```

Here Is My **Views.py**

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')
    model = Post
```

Here is my app **Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    path('register/',views.user_register,name='user_register'),
    path('post/(?P<pk>\d+)',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    path('post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/remove/',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    path('drafts/',views.PostDraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    path('post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),
    path('post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),
]
```

**Image**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbcfn.png

Here is my **post_confirm_delete.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are You sure you want to delete {{ object }}?</p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Confirm">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my Project **Urls.py**

```
"""blogpro URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView,LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
]
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: and also add the html template to see what request are you using calling in the form

Comment: @LinhNguyen Question Updated Please Check

Comment: where is the `object` context coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using path with regex which is not how it work [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#path), only use regex url string with re_path

it should be :

```
path('post/<int:pk>/remove/',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
```

Comment: Still Getting Error

Comment: can you add your html template ? for us to see how you calling the url, your urls.py still need to change since you getting `/post/(?P3\d+)/remove/` you can see the it included the regex pattern in your url you calling. after changing the path then it should be `/post/3/remove/` which is correct

Comment: my some post are deleting correctly but some are not deleting

Comment: i get this error `TypeError at /post/3/remove/
'str' object is not callable`

Comment: ok my next question is can you post your PostDetailView  code and the template of that view ? i need to see what you passing to the template because i don't know what the `object` context in your post_confirm_delete.html come from

Comment: you can use this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Go1yHB00hl8 as an example

Comment: i can delete my all new post but i can't delete my old posts

Comment: yeah that the problem i can't see which is your new post or old post because i don't know the template of your list, if you deleted then it shouldn't even be appear in your list

Comment: Thanks My Problem is Fix The Error is in my migrate i delete migrations folder and db.sqlite and re migrate and makemigrations and it worked

Comment: Thanks You For Your Time! the problem is in my migrations

Comment: Yeah forgot to migration will affect how your data is showing. You should also change all the path url like the docs said or they wont get the parameter. Glad i can help